# Find unmatched rows between tables with sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-insert

I am trying to find all the unmatched rows between 2 tables using SQL.
The table `codes` contains 6 million entries, and the table `burnt` contains 1 millions entries.
I have tried using `INSERT INTO SELECT`, but this didn't work, it crashed out after a while.

```
INSERT INTO unburnt
SELECT
    *
FROM
    codes T2
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM
           burnt T1
        WHERE
           T1.code = T2.code)
```

Any unmatched rows should be put into the `unburnt` table.
What would be the best way to handle this query?

The database table structure is the same for all 3 tables.

**codes**

- id
- code (TEXT)

**burnt**

- id
- code (TEXT)

**unburnt**

- id
- code (TEXT)

Comment: Would you please post the related table structures (`create table code`)?

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu I have edited the question to include the table structures

Comment: LEFT Join codes to burnt `union` left join burnt to codes  since mysql doesn't support full outer joins.

Comment: All the tables are structurally same? I asked for `create table code`. By the way, what's the storage engine type? is there any index in the tables? better post the `create table code`

Comment: What Indexes do you have?

Comment: Try this way: `INSERT INTO unburnt select a.id, a.text from codes a LEFT JOIN burnt b on a.id = b.id WHERE b.id IS NULL`

Comment: @JorgeCampos does that insert to the unburnt table per row, or does it insert after the query has finished?

Comment: It insert in one atomic operation if that is what you asking. It will fetch all rows first (this is done internally by the database) then insert each one.

Comment: @JorgeCampos yeah, that is what I was asking. I think the query I used caused it to crash out having to deal with this number of rows. Correct me if you think I am wrong. It ran fine for about 2 hours, by then crashed and I had to restart. Would using JOIN be more affective?

Comment: No, it won't. I just missed the number of rows in your question. Sorry for that!

Comment: maybe there's an easier way like copying/renaming the table and deleting where ID is in burnt

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking the INSERT into a set of smaller INSERTS:

```
INSERT INTO unburnt SELECT * ....  WHERE T1.code = T2.code and T2.ID between 1 and 100000) 
INSERT INTO unburnt SELECT * ....  WHERE T1.code = T2.code and T2.ID between 100001 and 200000)
etc.
```

Comment: You bring up a good point. I was thinking I could use PHP to go row by row and insert each time it does not match. I was interested to see if there was a way to handle that sort of thing with sql